# Silverlight XAML Designer

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Is there a XAML designer I can use to build my Silverlight GUI?

thanks

Lennie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few.  You can use Expression Blend, [XAMLPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx) and when it comes out, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

[Aurora XAML Designer for .NET 3.0 V2.0](http://www.tucows.com/preview/405565)

Answer (score 0):

Expression Blend 3 would be my first consideration.